# "Reverse" run a VBA script in excel

Tags: excel, vba

First timer with `VBA` here  :)

I have used a script to display html tags as html (instead of plain text) in excel. Script works great.  However I would like to know if it is possible to run a "`reverse`" version of this script to display the data as plain text showing the html tags.   If it is possible, how would I go about it?  Any help gratefully received!

Script is:

```
Sub DisplayHTMLContentProperly()
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Ie As Object
Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Ie.Visible = True 'to be tested
Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject ' for clipboard
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")


Set rng = Range("c2:c169")

For Each row In rng.Rows
For Each cell In row.Cells

Application.CutCopyMode = False
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
myString = " "
DataObj.SetText " "

If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
With Ie
.Visible = True
.Navigate "about:blank"
While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
.Document.body.InnerHTML = cell 'update to the cell that contains HTML you want converted

.ExecWB 17, 0 'Select all contents in browser
.ExecWB 12, 2 'Copy them

'get data from clipboard (due to copy method above) and paste it into the cell
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
myString = DataObj.GetText(1)
'MsgBox myString - to debug
cell = myString

'delete anything from the clipboard
DataObj.Clear
Application.CutCopyMode = False
DataObj.SetText " "

End With
End If
'Do Something
Set HTML = Nothing
Application.Wait (Now + 0.000000011574 * 1200)

Next cell
Next row

Ie.Quit
Set Ie = Nothing
Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox "I am now done with proper formatting of HTML column."

'move to see just summary page
Sheets("Summary").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: simplest way is to duplicate the sheet before running the script. And in the reverse script, simply delete new updated sheet and rename the duplicate sheet to original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, you will have to write a second procedure to do the reverse thing. The reverse procedure will be a completely different logic.

There cannot be an automatic for this, because some functions can be reversed some cannot.

For example imagine a `Sum` function that sums `1+2+3` wich results in `6` but this result cannot be reverted into `1+2+3` because the information about what it was before is not present anymore in that `6`. The `6` could also be the sum of `4+2`